# How to keep setting of a show/hide sidebar

Tags: javascript

I made a sidebar it is meant to show all time, only when it is clicked it will hide. But after hiding this if I refresh the page it get shown again. So I want to keep settings so if user hide this it wont appear until he press the show button doesnt matter the page refresh or he goto another page.

*(For example like facebook right chatbar which stays hidden or shown doesnt matter the page refresh or anything)*

I guess some changes on JS will do the job but im not sure & not a coder so help me do it.

**the JS code I used:**

```
<script language=javascript type='text/javascript'>
function hideDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        document.getElementById('hideShow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
            document.hideShow.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else { // IE 4
            document.all.hideShow.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}

function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        document.getElementById('hideShow').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
            document.hideShow.visibility = 'visible';
        } else { // IE 4
            document.all.hideShow.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML and CSS

```
<div id="hideShow" ..etc>
    My content
</div>
```

and this to call the JavaScript to hide it:

```
<a href="javascript:hideDiv()">Hide Div</a>
```

and this to show it:

```
<a href="javascript:showDiv()">show Div</a>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to support IE4-6, NS4-6? Microsoft doesn't even support IE6 anymore...

Comment: @josh no i just copied the code so it was written in 2004 so thats why it is coded like that

Answer (score 2):

Something like this! here you have a function to read the cookie, because set a cookie is easy, but read it not to much.

```
readCookie = function (name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return "es";
    }

function hideDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
    document.getElementById('hideShow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  else {
   if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
     document.hideShow.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
   else { // IE 4
    document.all.hideShow.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
  }
 document.cookie = 'show=false';
}

function showDiv() {
if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else {
if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
document.hideShow.visibility = 'visible';
}
else { // IE 4
document.all.hideShow.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
}
document.cookie = 'show=true';
}

if(readCookie('show') == "true"){
 showDiv();
}
else {
 hideDiv();
}
```

good luck

Comment: i copied all your function and modified, so you can replace all your code

Comment: i replaced but not working because i guess i  didnt set cookie so how do i create & set the state of bar visibility in cookie

Comment: the first time the cookie will not exist so "readCookie('show') == "true" " will be false, so it will execute hideDiv().
when you execute showDiv(), the cookie changes to "true".

Comment: you have a bug in this line "document.getElementById('hideShow').style.visibility = 'hidden';"
check because it's not finding the 'hideShow' id so the script is crashing

Comment: Hey @ledokt try putting your script in the bottom of the page, you're fetching for an element that doesn't exists yet

Answer (score 1):

You need a javascript class to read and write cookies. This way, you can write the state of the sidebar in the cookie when user interacts with it. When the page loads, you read the state from the cookie, and set visibility accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the state of the bar's visibility in a variable somewhere. Since you are using (I assume) only JS, you'll probably need to access the user's cookies.

How to Set a Cookie in JS: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/settinga.htm
How to Read a Cookie in JS: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/readinga.htm

Comment: ya i want to know how do i now save the state of the bars visibility in a variable and read it from cooks

Comment: Did you follow my links? There are two of them. One shows you how to set a cookie. The other shows you how to read a cookie. Once you can set and read the value, you can hide/show the bar accordingly using javascript. In addition, if my answer doesn't make sense to you, you really need to UNDERSTAND what you're doing before just doing it.